# How to declare image array and manipulate src value of its variables?

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, variables

I know this is beyond simple, but I just can't get it to work no matter what. I'm just having a hard time coming to terms with jQuery syntax and even grasping how to handle variables and arrays. Anyone kind enough to help me sort out this mess?

```
// declaring array and setting same image source for all variables in it

var imgarray1 = ['html.(src="img0.jpg")', 'html.(src="img0.jpg")', 'html.(src="img0.jpg")'];


// when I click any image with class myimg, pass source of clicked image to imgarray1

$('img.myimg').click(function () {
('imgarray1').append(this)
});


// show second variable in array myimg as picture

$('imgarray1').html(src='idx=1');
```

why no work? :(

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's a fantasy card game; this part of the code is meant to let players pick available cards from a list of images... for each click I want to add that pic's source to the array that will represent the player's initial hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f0x2pj4a/7/):

```js
// declare the array
var imgarray1 = [];

// bind on click - select the image
$('img.myimg').click(function () {
    // insert image to array
    imgarray1.push(this.src);
});

// bind on click - show the "hand"
$('#showcards').on('click', function(){
    // loop through array elements
    imgarray1.forEach(function(src) {
        // add current element to the appropriate div
        $('#hand').append(
            $('<img/>', {src: src, width: 100})
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="deck">
    <img class="myimg" src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo.gif" width="100"/>
    <img class="myimg" src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" width="100"/>
    <img class="myimg" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iWkJWpzsrw0/UxdyOspVimI/AAAAAAAAATw/zrMWxvkPbtg/s1600/Batman+Logo+%282%29.png" width="100"/>
    <img class="myimg" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/fictionalcrossover/images/c/ca/Batman_logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20131110212948" width="100"/>
</div>
<button id="showcards">Show Hand</button>
<div id="hand"></div>
```

I've commented the code so this should suffice in understanding what's going on - but let me know if something's unclear.

Comment: This should work, I'll look into it now. Thanks a million! :-) btw, Did you notice my previous comment? This code is for letting players pick their initial cards on a fantasy card game I'm trying to develop.

Comment: I did. Yet, since there is not enough code for the entire game here (and there shouldn't be), I'm looking for the specific task you are trying to achieve with this specific snippet and not the general idea of it.

Comment: Sure! The main task is: "Whenever img.myimg is clicked, pass img src to array player1cards"; then in another moment I want to show contents of player1 cards in divs I'll mark p1c1, p1c2, etc...." Here, I'll post the actual code I'm using to try and get this effect on just one card for test (still not working...): 
$('#card040').click(function () {
    imgarray1.push(this.src);
    $('div#p1c2').append(
        $('<img/>', {src: this.src, width: this.width})
);
});
});

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. This should now provide the full answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me! I think I'll manage to adapt this to my needs. Best wishes!

Comment: If you find that this answers your question, please accept it as the solution to the question.

Comment: Of course! I'll do that immediately; thanks again for your help!